# Nothing showing on screen with custom listview adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

As the title states, I'm having some troubles getting my custom listview adapter to work properly. The app displays nothing on the list, and gives just a blank white screen. I tested my data with a simple list I already have setup, and that worked just fine.

History.java

```
public class History {
    public String score;
    public String gametype;
    public int icon;

    public History() {
        super();
    }

    public History(String score, String gametype, int icon) {
        super();
        this.score = score;
        this.gametype = gametype;
        this.icon = icon;
    }
}
```

HistoryAdapter.java

```
public class HistoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<History> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResId;
    History data[] = null;

    public HistoryAdapter(Context context, int layoutResId, History[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResId, data);
        this.layoutResId = layoutResId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        HistoryHolder holder = null;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResId, parent, false);

            holder = new HistoryHolder();
            holder.imageIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.textTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.gameType);
            holder.textScore = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.score);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (HistoryHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        History history = data[position];
        holder.textScore.setText(history.score);
        holder.textTitle.setText(history.gametype);
        holder.imageIcon.setImageResource(history.icon);


        return convertView;
    }

    static class HistoryHolder
    {
        ImageView imageIcon;
        TextView textTitle;
        TextView textScore;
    }
}
```

Implementation

```
for(int i = 0; i < games.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = games.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject gameStats = games.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject(TAG_STATS);
                    type[i] = c.getString(TAG_TYPE);
                    champId[i] = c.getString("championId");
                    cs[i] = gameStats.getString("minionsKilled");
                    kills[i] = gameStats.getString("championsKilled");
                    deaths[i] = gameStats.getString("numDeaths");
                    assists[i] = gameStats.getString("assists");
                    win[i] = gameStats.getString("win");

                    if(win[i].equals("true"))
                        win[i] = "Victory";
                    else
                        win[i] = "Defeat";

                    if(type[i].equals("RANKED_SOLO_5x5"))
                        type[i] = "Ranked (Solo)";

                    if(type[i].equals("CAP_5x5"))
                        type[i] = "TeamBuilder";

                    if(type[i].equals("NORMAL"))
                        type[i] = "Unranked";

                    score[i] = kills[i] +"/" + deaths[i] + "/" + assists[i];

                    historyData[i] = new History(score[i], champId[i], R.drawable.ic_launcher); // Placeholder image

                }

                adapter = new HistoryAdapter(MatchHistoryActivity.this,
                        R.layout.list_adapter,
                        historyData);

                list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:background="#111111"> 
    </ListView>
```

list_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="#111111"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:textColor="#C49246"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="0/0/0 KDA"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gameType"
        android:textColor="#C49246"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/score"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: change your `ListView` background with `transparent` and also change your `ListItem Relative Layout` background with  `android:background="#some other color"`

Comment: @SimplePlan Doing this had no results, and I am left with the same thing, a blank white screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should replace `ArrayAdapter` by `BaseAdapter` and implement all required method e.g. `getItemId(), getItem(), getCount(), getView()`.
It should work fine!.
Below is example code of mine, dont care about what is MusicModel.

```
protected class MusicCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Activity context;
        private List<MusicModel> musicModelList;
        private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");

        public MusicCustomAdapter(Activity context, List<MusicModel> musicModelList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.musicModelList = musicModelList;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return this.musicModelList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.musicModelList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.song_item, null);
            }

            MusicModel musicModel = (MusicModel) getItem(position);

            TextView tvMusicName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_song_name);
            tvMusicName.setText(musicModel.getName());

            TextView tvArtist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_artist);
            tvArtist.setText(musicModel.getArtist());

            TextView tvDuration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_duration);
            tvDuration.setText(sdf.format(musicModel.getDuration()));

            ImageView imgThumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
            imgThumbnail.setImageDrawable(musicModel.getThumbnail());

            return view;
        }
    }
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `getCount()` in your custom adapter.
It will return the number of entries in your ListView.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return myArrayList.size();
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why we need to overrid getCount() method and vice versa. I have tried to override getCount() and getItem() method but my application crash then.

Comment: Post your logs if you want help. The adapter uses `getCount()` method to determine number of items to display in the list.

Comment: After I replaced ArrayAdapter by BaseAdapter everything is working fine, thanks for your answer.